# UPS to keep router running for 8 hours at a time

Tags: power, ups

We have a modem / router combination on a building site. The router keeps going down because the power keeps getting turned off for electrical work.

Is there a type of high capacity UPS that could keep power flowing to the modem router combi, ideally for eight hours or more? 
Note that all the network users are on tablets / phones,
which have batteries and so are not directly affected by the power outage.

I spoke to a local UPS supplier and they said for that I’d need a mini generator, but that sounds excessive.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (hardware shopping). Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask). Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that when the power goes down, the router is not the only device to loose power. You probably won't get a lot of help if its just the router you need to supply from power. How about the modem and pc's?

Comment: @LPChip its a modem / router combi. There are no PCs / laptops everything runs on tablets / phones.

Comment: I've nominated this for reopening - the user was not asking for specific hardware, they were looking at a class of solution or why this was not viable.  I think this is on-topic.

Comment: Agreed. Vote added.

Comment: The answer will probably depend on the current draw of the modem-router - but if its a typical system which uses say 10 watts then you can just get a bigger UPS, which will have a bigger battery and last longer. - in fact a regular "low end" UPS would even do you - the lower the wattage, the longer the runtime - so a typical 1kw UPS which can power a 500 watt load for 10 minutes would (very,very roughly) last for 100 minutes at 50 watts or 500 minutes - 8 hours at 10 watts.

Comment: Alternatively, if you are looking for something light, and the router takes 12 volts (which is typical), you may be able to find a lithium jump starter/power pack (from a car accessories company) which can power the wifi router instead - I've not used this, but in theory https://www.amazon.com/DBPOWER-18000mAh-Portable-Starter-Charging/dp/B01D42TYFC/ref=pd_sim_263_6?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=N7XE4JGP49SCCAR5B6EP may work and provide 8 hours runtime for even a 20 watt router.  (Leave the router plugged in to this, and this plugged in to the mains)

Comment: I wonder if the person you spoke to mistook the router for a power tool of a similar name. Running a router (power tool) for hours would practically require a generator.

Comment: @davidgo - I'd have never thought of that. In the UK route [root] & rout [pout] have two different pronunciations, which extend to IP router & wood-cutting router; the fact that in the US they're homonyms just didn't occur to me ;)

Comment: good point.. i can confirm its a router as in a network router with a built in modem (rather than a power tool)

Answer (score 2):

For an extended time period of *"eight hours or more"*, you really need a decent (if not accurate) measurent of the power consumed by the equipment you want to keep running.
IOW you need to use a power meter such as a Kill-a-Watt, that will report the actual number of watts consumed over a period of time.
Use that number of watts (for an eight-hour period) (plus a margin of 20%) to specify/purchase/install an adequate UPS.

> Is there a type of high capacity UPS that could keep power flowing ...

For a price there are battery systems to power a local grid.
Besides the home and SOHO UPS units often seen, there are larger commercial units available from dealers instead of retailers.